# Graph line becomes thin when value is 0

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Made this with Amcharts V3

I've set line thickness in my graph to 3. Whenever the readings are 0, the graph line will then lie on x axis for those values, and here the thickness becomes 1. But if the values are more than 0, then the thickness is correct of 3.

[image]

Here is the function which renders the graphs:

```
    function drawChart(chartData, color)
    {
        var ballon = '<div class="ballon"><p class="heading">[[date_full]]</p><div class="values"><span class="chart_label">Score</span><span class="chart_reading">[[score]]</span></div></div>';
        return AmCharts.makeChart("score_chart",
        {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "none",
            "dataProvider": chartData,
            "valueAxes": [
            {
                "axisAlpha": 0,
                "gridAlpha": 0.5,
                "position": "left",
                "minimum": 0,
                "maximum": 100,
                "labelsEnabled": true,
                "gridColor": "#E9EBED",
                "axisColor": "#E9EBED",
                "color": "#68737D",
                "fontSize": 13
            }],
            "graphs": [
            {
                "id": "g1",
                "balloonText": ballon,
                "bullet": "round",
                "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
                "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
                "title": "red line",
                "valueField": "score",
                "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
                "lineColor": color,
                "lineThickness": 3,
                "bulletBorderThickness": 3,
                "balloonColor": "white",
                "balloon": {
                    "borderAlpha": 0,
                    "borderThickness": 0,
                    "fillAlpha": 0
                },
                "bulletSize": 10
            }],
            "chartCursor":
            {
                "limitToGraph": "g1",
                "cursorColor": color
            },
            "categoryField": "date",
            "categoryAxis":
            {
                "parseDates": false,
                "axisColor": "lightgrey",
                "gridAlpha": 0,
                "color": "#68737D",
                "fontSize": 13
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please post you codes.

Comment: posted the code

Comment: @RajanSohal This is a known limitation - the chart clips everything within the plot area by design. There is no fix for this outside of changing the value axis minimum to a small negative number (you might also need to set `strictMinMax: true` in your value axis) so that it will display properly.

Comment: is this limitation also in V4 of amcharts?

Comment: This is also in v4 as well. There is a workaround to disable the mask/clipping on the series (`series.mainContainer.mask = undefined;`), but it will cause some visual glitches when zooming/panning the chart, as the mask is used to clip the line so it doesn't interfere with other elements (like value axis labels and such) and disabling it will break that. Caveat emptor.